# Need help showing $\mathbb E(5^x) = (1+4p)^n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-theorem

I have no idea where to even begin on this problem. The problem reads:

Suppose $X$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $p$. Show with a simple calculation (using the binomial theorem) the $\mathbb E(5^x) = (1+4p)^n$

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why don't you start with writing the expected value :$\sum{n\choose k} 5^kp^k(1-p)^{n-k}$? What will be this sum then? I am sure you can write the answer yourself below.